# Quebra de linha dentro de tags HTML no Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentação

Como habilitar a quebra de linha dentro de *tags* HTML para que fiquem desta forma?

```
<input 
      class="someClass"
      id="someId"
      name="someName"
      ng-model="vm.model"
      ng-click="vm.someAction()"/>
```

Quando formato o texto no Visual Code (Alt+Shift+F) ele deixa as tags HTML dessa forma:

```
<input class="someClass" id="someId" name="someName" value="someValue" ng-model="vm.model" ng-click="vm.someAction"/>
```

Ele remove todas as quebras de linha que eu havia inserido. No NetBeans não tenho esse problema. Já alterei as configurações do Code, baixei extensões e nada funciona.

Comment: B. Maríclio > Referente a quebra de linhas em questão do
> **HTML**, não é **"bom uso"** fazer isto com o "código" de marcação de texto. Por isto o **Visual Code Studio** quebra do jeito que você está
> falando. >Se você perceber, cada linguagem de programação que você
> fizer no **Visual Code** ele quebra as linhas de acordo com o "bom uso
> do código".

Answer (score 2):

Realmente está faltando essa funcionalidade no Visual Studio Code e, se já existe, ainda não encontrei nos atalhos.

Mas para habilitar a quebra de linhas na mão mesmo você vai em
**Files > Preferences > Settings**, depois, no módulo **Editor**, você procura por `editor.wordWrap` que vai estar **off** basta mudar para **on**.

[image: quebra de linhas automaticamente Visual Code]

Essa alteração vai executar quebras de linha automaticamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo. Mas encontrei um pluggin muito bom, o Beaultify https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

Comment: Obrigado pela dica amigo. Mas encontrei um pluggin muito bom, o Beaultify https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify